# Protect against hacking / break-in attempts on servers

Tags: internet, webserver, port

I've recently set up a Confluence server in my home, and use CCProxy to route external port 80 to internal port 8090 that the Confluence server uses. But I see that every now and then unknown IP addresses appear in the CCProxy log. I guess that this stems from robots scanning random IP's for available ports to check for vulnerabilities.

I saw the same thing when I opened port 22 on my NAS to enable SFTP. Suddenly my NAS emailed me about blocking this and that IP address that had tried to access through SSH (which also uses port 22). In this case I just changed the SFTP port to some random port up in the thousands area.

But what can I do to protect against this? What is reasonable to do to protect open ports? Or can I just lie back and trust that the username/password login is enough to ward off hacking attempts?

Comment: Both robot scanning (including on unpected ports like 23) and ssh scriptkiidie login attemts are sadly the norm. If you get fewer then a few hundred of those per day then you are either lucky or something upstream already block them. As for non standard usernane and password: Yes, never use an advious username. Those are in lists. And a password should already be hard to guess and very much not standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, these are bots that scan for open ports and they usually perform a dictionary attack with known email and password combinations.

Given that they only scan on certain ports, you could change the portnumber to something other than port 80, and add that port in the url, for example: mydomain.com:8090 to make it work.

But if you setup that after 5 bad login attempts the ip address is permanently banned, you are safe too. You will get lots of these attacks in your log, and if your log is detailed enough, you will most likely keep seeing the same hostname or pattern reappear from a different IP Address. Do not even consider to only temp-ban.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of doing this.

I'd suggest setting up a VPN and requiring access via VPN before accessing Confluence.

The next thing would be to use HTTPS.  If you put it behind a proxy, you could even require client certificates.

Using something like fail2ban and decent passwords will stop brute Force attacks, but not exploiting vulnerable code in Confluence if it exists (and my guess is that it might). Preventing access to the app altogether until done other verification has taken place must be better.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Both your answer and LPChip's answer were good answers.  Unfortunately I don't have the rep to upvote your answer.